# How come in `./node_modules/googleapis` I see a `build/src` folder instead of a `src` folder

Tags: node.js, ember.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I have this new Ember project and I installed the google node sdk via `npm install googleapis --save-dev`. I then installed `ember-cli-es6-transform` in hopes of importing the es6 modules from the google api node client.

However I noticed in `./node_modules/googleapis` there is a `build/src` folder instead of a `src` folder. In the [Github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/src), it's just a `src` folder. Why is this? This is causing my imports to be wonky while using `ember-cli-es6-transform`.

This is all that is in my devDependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli": "~3.1.4",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.6.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-es6-transform": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.1.1",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^10.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-data": "~3.1.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-source": "~3.1.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.0.0",
    "googleapis": "^40.0.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3",
    "sass": "^1.22.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

npm does not require that a repository place its main file in any particular place or name it index.js. It is recommended that you look at a repo's package.json and use the path and file listed under the "main" key.

You can see it at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/cb9326b902d6c203c498a2e269f256bcc3b23c2d/package.json#L42

googleapis chooses to build its source prior to putting it on npm to make it easier for us to use, hence the build/src directory.

For more information regarding the "main" key in package.json, see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

Note that ember-cli-es6-transform allows you to specify any path, so just put the correct path in as an argument.

```
app.import('node_modules/googleapis/build/src/index.js', {
  using: [
    { transformation: 'es6', as: 'googleapis' }
  ]
});
```

Comment: When you say it "builds" its source, does that mean the npm package is actually already written in es5? I tried using the `es6` transformation and it still gives me `Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'googleapis' imported from ...`

Comment: No, the /src is in TypeScript, the /build/src is ES6. However, it looks like build/src/index.js does not have a default export.